# Crystal report - 2 logic in single column

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have requirement in Crystal report where we have to implement 2 concept in one column.
For eg: in below screenshot, 
   if we have numbers we need to sum up and display as one row.
   if it is variable row. It should remain as single row.

```
Material    Quantity    Price
O Ring      1           5.61
O Ring      1           Fixed 
O Ring      1           5.61
O Ring      1           Fixed
```

Output should be,

```
Material    Quantity    Price
O Ring      1           11.22
O Ring      1           Fixed 
O Ring      1           Fixed
```

Kindly pour us some suggestions if any.

Answer (score 1):

First note that your current table design is very flawed, because you are trying to store numeric and text information in the same `Price` column, both as text.  This means that to sum up any prices, we have to cast to a number, and then cast back again to text to report with the other text only values.  You would be much better off *not* storing text in the `Price` column, and making that column numeric.

That being said, the following query appears to do what you want:

```
SELECT
    Material, MAX(Quantity) AS Quantity,
    CAST(SUM(CAST(Price AS numeric(9,2))) AS varchar(15)) AS Price
FROM yourTable
WHERE Price <> 'Fixed'
GROUP BY Material
UNION ALL
SELECT Material, Quantity, Price
FROM yourTable
WHERE Price = 'Fixed';
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: This is the existing functionality of the report. Can you please help me in modifying it to get desired expected output.
If Not (Val({sm07.FNSM07StructLineNo}) <> 0 And Trim({SM07.FNSM07NodeID_BOM_SM}) <> "") Then  
(
    if {SM07.FNSM07InclFixPrice} = "0" or {InvParameters.FNInvParametersFixPriMatICU} = 0 then
        ToText ( {CalcMaterial.FNCalcMaterialOrderDiscount},{CalcTotals.FNCalcTotalsAmmdec})
    else 
        "Fixed"
)
Else
    ""